# passing model from view to controller in mvc3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, controller

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.AllManagementActions)
{
 <tr>
     <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
     </td>
     <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
     </td>
```

I want to pass all these values to my controller. The ID , the name, etc.
Can't i just pass the item itself?
This is my current code, but it doesn't work.

```
<a class="complete" title="My Action" data-url="@Url.Action("Submit", "Period", new { tpId = Model.Id ,it = item})" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

It works if I pass item.name, item.id,item.number,etc

Can i pass the model ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't iterate in your views - use [editor templates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/) for the type.

Have a '~/shared/EditorTemplates/ManagementAction.ascx' (or `.cshtml` if using razor) that renders a single `ManagementAction`.

In the view, instead of iterating use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllManagementActions)
```

Comment: also for displying a table he could use the WebGrid from the WebHelper Class tha recieves only an IEnumerable of your data and knows what to do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.99%29.aspx

Comment: If he created an editor template, he will be able to pass the model to a controller?

Comment: @aquinas - Yes. I have used this myself to get models that contain collections passed in as a single strongly typed parameter to an action.

Comment: I guess I thought he wanted to be able to edit *one* of the ManagementActions in the list. Maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can pass the entire model, but you should use a submit button instead of of an anchor tag and also put your code inside a

```
using(Html.BeginForm)
{
   @foreach (var item in Model.AllManagementActions)
   {
      //your desire.
   }
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

in your controller you will recieve the model on post

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveViewData(YourModel model)
 {
    //your logic.
 }
```